# Get a class width/height/etc.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I search for a class or id's `width` value (or anything else, say `height`, `color`, etc), and use that in CSS?

I am using Bootstrap, and have a container.  I'd like to set the padding of another class to be the same width as the container.

I have found that via javascript console on the site itself, I can do:

```
var wid = $(".container").width();
```

which returns `750`.

How do I implement that in my CSS?

```
.sampOutput{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-right:100%;
}
```

Where the `padding-right` would be `750`.

Then I'd want to get the `color` of my `body` and set that as the `border` color.

How do I get the various values of a class/id's style?

Edit: I'm learning, and see Javascript (or jquery) may help, but if there are other ways, I'm open to it!

Answer (score 2):

you can get and set `css` elements with the [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method.

```
var width = $(".container").width();
var color = $("body").css("color");

$("#element").css({
    border: "solid 1px " + color,
    "padding-right": width + "px"
});
```

There are two main ways to place the code on your page (the third is outdated and probably shouldn't be mentioned):

Method one inline within the head:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            // Your JavaScript goes here
        </script>
```

Method two include the JavaScript file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/path/to/javascript/file.js"></script>
```

If you want to modify the stylesheet directly, this cannot be done within the browser. You have to use a preprocessor such as [sass/scss](http://sass-lang.com/) (most popular) or [less](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: Where in my HTML file would I put that code? In the header between a `<script type = "text/javascript>[that code]</script>`?

Comment: @BruceWayne I have updated the answer with the different methods of using the code. Most people prefer method two.

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables in CSS/SASS/LESS and then use them as values, but in many cases it will not give you the actual with (for example width) of the element. SASS/LESS are rather powerful, I think you can do the trick with this preprocessors, but not in pure CSS. If you want to get the actual width of the element and use this value for another elements styles, you should implement it via Javascript. I see you're using jQuery, so in jQuery it should be something like this:

```
var wid = $(".container").width(); // for example returns 750
$(".container").css({
  "border": "1px solid black",
  "padding-right": wid + "px" // set padding-right to 750
});
```

Comment: Actually you can use variables in css: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, oh, it's new for me, thank you for the info!

Comment: No problem, I haven't used it much though, so I don't really know what powers it has.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, I guess there are some issues with browser support, isn't it?

Comment: Looks like everything but IE supports them (at least the important browsers)  http://caniuse.com/#search=var So you should decide if what you want/need to support first.

Comment: This looks promising - but as I mentioned in @GetOffMyLawn's post, where would I put this in my HTML file? (I'm learning HTML+Javascript, so am not positive where it would go)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, I think it's to early to use them, imho.

Comment: You can put it in one of two places. In the HTML between script tags or an external JavaScript file https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_JavaScript_within_a_webpage

Comment: @BruceWayne, it should go after all HTML content, because the page should be rendered, if you want to manipulate styles properly. I suggest to place the script with this logic right before the `</body>` closing tag.

Comment: @CommercialSuicide - Oh man, awesome!  That's great.  A related question - is this a common thing to do, or am I being kludgy and perhaps asking an [`XY Problem`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?  Basically, I'm using Bootstrap to make a row and want my border to go to the width of the current row's div...

Comment: @BruceWayne, if you can implement the markup only using CSS - better use CSS, if not - use Javascript. I believe that it can be implemented in pure CSS, but I also think that it's not very bad to change paddings programmatically on page load.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to do it with pure CSS, as I'd like to just have "one place" to change all this (instead of some classes/id styles up top, then others below), so I'll keep hunting around.  However, there's a lot packed in to this answer for me to learn, so thanks! (I'll keep it open for now just in case there are other methods, but this is working for me :D )

Comment: @BruceWayne, nice to hear, that it helps you! And yes, if someone will suggest a good solution, I'd like to look at that too ;)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
  var cPadding = $('.my-container').css('padding');
  var bColor = $('body').css('color');
  $('.my-p').css('padding', cPadding).css("border", "1px solid " + bColor);
});
```

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
    color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container my-container">
  <p class="my-p">Welcome to Bootstrap</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The more traditional approach is to not use JavaScript to modify the stylesheet itself, but to use it to modify *inline* styles. That is: `<div style="padding-right:750px">`.

So in this case, you would want to do something like:

```
var wid = $(".container").width();
$(".sampOutput").css({
  "padding-right": wid + "px"
});
```

That will select element with the class of `sampOutput` and modify its `style` attribute to include `padding-right:750px`.

Comment: With js you can create css rules, and modify exisiting ones as long as the stylesheet they belong to are from the same origin as the site or the acess is allowed by http header. [MDN: CSSStyleSheet.insertRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule)